# Selenium WebDriver and C# (VS): Look for a specific header string

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying, without luck, to use IJavaScriptExecutor to find a specific header string in a page. Here's the html code form the page:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <h2>Edit Page <a href="http://www.webtest.bugrit.net/wordpress/wp-admin/post-
   new.php?post_type=page" class="add-new-h2">Add New</a></h2>
<div id...
```

The text I need to check for is the "Edit Page" string.

This is the closest I've come, which isn't very close:

```
var element = FFDriver.Instance.FindElements(By.ClassName("add-new-h2"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = FFDriver.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;

if (js != null) {
    string innerHtml = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(innerHtml);
    if (innerHtml.Equals("Edit Page")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, I realize that the text I should expect to get from that code isn't the exact string "Edit Page". But shouldn't it return something? When I enable the MessageBox line, the innerHtml string is empty.

Or, of couse - if someone knows another, possible easier, way to check for the existance of a specific string inside a specific html tag, I'm all ears.

Comment: so what does `element.Text` return?

Comment: Do you mean innerHtml.Text? That method doesn't work. innterHtml.toString however, crashes with an "object not set to a reference..." error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element returns you `<a>` element, not `<h2>`. Your `<a>` doesn't contain `Edit Page` string.

Try find your element like this to the parent element `<h2>` (only if class name `add-new-h2` is unique, otherwise you will get the first matching one):

```
var element = FFDriver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a[@class='add-new-h2']/.."));
var containsText = element.Text.Contains("Edit Page");
```

Comment: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do `.First` at the very end: `FFDriver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath(".//a[@class='add-new-h2']/..")).First();`